# What is the format of dateTime.Now in ExecuteSQL call of ORMLite?

Tags: c#, postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

I am using version 3.8.5.0 of ServiceStack.ormLite.dll.

We are using postgreSql server. Our postgreSQL server has it locale set to en-GB (in postgres.conf we have set dateStyle parameter to "ISO, DMY").

In our web application, when we pass a raw SQL statement as:

```
  var insertSql = string.Format("insert into ReportTable values (
                                    '{0}', '{1}',)",
                                          message.Id, DateTime.Now);
```

and use ExecuteSql(insertSql), I get date-range out of date in postgres as the date is in MDY and the database expects DMY.

However if I do:

```
    var insertSql = string.Format("insert into ReportTable values (
                                    '{0}', 'now',)",
                                          message.Id);
```

the insert works.

I know I could set

```
 <globalization Culture="en-GB"/>
```

However, I have some threads that do some background processing and I will have to change their culture as well to get this working.

Any ideas if there is any other way I can solve this issue on the ormLite library?

Comment: Why would you want to pass raw SQL at all, rather than using parameterized SQL? At that point, you wouldn't need to worry about the conversion *or* SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was aware of the conversion issue being resolved by using  parameterised  SQL but did not even think about SQL injection. I will change my code to cater for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must format `DateTime.Now` the way postgreSQL (or any RDBMS for that matter) expects it.

```
var insertSql = string.Format("insert into ReportTable values (
                                '{0}', '{1:your format here}',)",
                                      message.Id, DateTime.Now);
```

For example, if your RDBMS expects dates in the day-month-year format, then you need to pass this:

```
var insertSql = string.Format("insert into ReportTable values (
                                '{0}', '{1:dd-MM-yyyy}',)",
                                      message.Id, DateTime.Now);
```

Of course you could also use parameter objects as Jon Skeet suggested, although there could be a reason why you specifically want to use a `string`.

Comment: Pg will prefer ISO dates, YYYY-MM-DD. So should most DBs.

Comment: Yeah but the OP said he specifically set the config on DMY so I figured my answer should take that into account. ;)

Comment: Sure. Just noting that Pg will *always* accept an ISO date.

Comment: Thanks. If I don't change Pg to DMY and leave it with the default installation of MDY, as Craig mentioned, I should be okay if I format to ISO YYYY-MM-DD. Just asking again to be absolutely sure this will work?

Comment: Since I don't know Pg I can't answer that but I would believe it's true since I've seen this in other RDBMS as well. In any case this should be dead easy to verify. ;)